# Druid : org.apache.druid.query.ResourceLimitExceededException

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

First I ingest 2 mysql tables into kafka and then I loaded that kafka topics in druid.Now I have 2 datasources in druid in which one datasource includes upto 6000 records and another datasource includes upto 720000 records. I was trying to fetch records from both datasources using druid sql join query but it shows following error :

```
Resource limit exceeded / Subquery generated results beyond maximum[100000] /
org.apache.druid.query.ResourceLimitExceededException
```

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM unsold_all LEFT JOIN unsold_hotel_data ON unsold_all.booking_hotel_code=unsold_hotel_data.hotel_code
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

To override the default limit on subquery size, change the `druid.server.http.maxSubqueryRows` configuration entry.

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/index.html#server-configuration

However, doing so will impact the performance of your queries and is not recommended without caution.

Consider using filters appropriately to reduce the number of rows in the subquery.  (1) add a time period `WHERE` clause instead of querying all data, and (2) add a GROUP BY to generate statistics rather than just doing `SELECT *`.

It wasn't clear in the OP so just checking that you are aware of the constraints on the left- and right-hand-side of the `JOIN` and that you had ingested the right data into the right data structures in Druid.
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/datasource.html#join

Comment: Thanx for ur reply. In which config file I get druid.server.http.maxSubqueryRows entry ?? Or in which file I can add this property ??

Comment: I believe these are set on the broker runtime properties file:

Comment: Yes. Issue is solved. I set the druid.server.http.maxSubqueryRows=1000000 in broker runtime properties file.